# Retrieve id token after authentication with Auth0's Lock

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I am using Auth0's Lock widget to get users authenticated.

How do I go about getting an `idToken` once that's done?

Answer (score 0):

The `idToken` is within the `authResult` parameter available on `authenticated` event if your Lock's options specify `id_token` in the `auth.responseType` option:

```
var lock = new Auth0Lock(
          '<your-client-id>',
          '<your-auth0-domain>',
          {
              auth: {
                  responseType: 'token id_token',
              },
              container: 'lockRoot'
          }
    );
lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) {
      console.log('id token: ' + authResult.idToken);
}
```